# Is it possible bulk insert to always encrypted table using SSIS Bulk insert task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

I need **bulk insert** to a **Always Encrypted table** using **SSIS Bulk insert task** because if it is minimize the modifications for existing packages. Otherwise it will be change for all Bulk insert tasks in existing packages.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try?   What is the error?

Comment: Take a look at these links, they might be helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160577/is-it-possible-to-bulk-insert-data-into-a-table-that-has-columns-encrypted-with

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4162/writing-always-encrypted-data-with-integration-services-2016/